# Why won't the JFrame respond?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I have a `JFrame` and two `JPanels`.  When my program starts it adds the first `JPanel` to the `JFrame`.  The `JFrame` components (x, minimize, `KeyListener`, etc) all work.  but when I remove the first `JPanel` and add the second `JPanel` the `JFrame`'s 'x' button wont work nor will any `KeyListener` or `MouseListener`.  How can I get the `JFrame` to function correctly?

Comment: Can you show us your code? (A runnable program that is as short as possible and demonstrates the problem is ideal)

Comment: Actually I continued to explore the problem and as soon as I add(component) any button the first panel the jframe freaks out. Also I tried bypassing the first panel on to the second and the Jframe won't work as well.

Comment: @Ash AKA an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: Please use the correct capitalization for J2SE classes (e.g. JFrame and JPanel) so we can be sure they ARE J2SE and not some 3rd party (and poorly named) classes.

Answer (score 0):

If fundamental GUI operations cease to function after you have made changes to your components, there is a good chance that you have run foul of the Swing threading model.  Swing is single threaded and you need to follow a simple rule of ensuring that actions which effect painting of the GUI are done in the Event Dispatch Thread or you run the risk of deadlock or other unwanted behavior.

You have a couple options.  You can employ a [`SwingWorker`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), or you can instantiate a `Runnable` and drop it into `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` or `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait`.  Take a look at [this link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for concepts around threading in Swing.